# GWT 2.4 IE8 issues

Tags: java, gwt

I'm using GWT 2.4 (and I can't upgrade my version to 2.5)
I'm having the following issue: when I use Chrome, Firefox or Internet Explorer 9 o 10, my system works pretty good; by using Internet Explorer 8, my systems doesn't work at all; it shows a blank page to the user and I get the following javascript error:

> Dettagli errore pagina Web
>
> Agente utente: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
>   Timestamp: Thu, 5 Sep 2013 10:56:58 UTC
>
> Messaggio: Argomento non valido.
>   Linea: 28410
>   Carattere: 54
>   Codice: 0
>   URI: http://app.it:8080/myApp/F662F41B287D1686DCB056062754DFEB.cache.html

I was searching on the net and I found this link: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6665
In this GWT issue it is explained that GWT 2.4 has some problems with IE8 and chromeframe; I did what they suggested; in fact what I did is:

- in my application HTML page I added the following meta-tag:meta ***http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"***
- I created my custom ***PropertyProviderGenerator*** (see code below)
- In my .gwt.xml file I specified to use my custom PropertyProviderGenerator (see code below)

**PropertyProviderGenerator**

```
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.TreeLogger;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.ConfigurationProperty;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.PropertyProviderGenerator;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.SortedSet;

public class CustomUserAgentPropertyGenerator implements PropertyProviderGenerator {

    private static final List<String> VALID_VALUES = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"ie6", "ie8", "gecko1_8", "safari", "opera", "ie9"});

    private static UserAgentPropertyGeneratorPredicate[] predicates =
            new UserAgentPropertyGeneratorPredicate[] {

        // opera
        new UserAgentPropertyGeneratorPredicate("opera")
        .getPredicateBlock()
        .println("return (ua.indexOf('opera') != -1);")
        .returns("'opera'"),

    // webkit family (chrome, safari and chromeframe).
    new UserAgentPropertyGeneratorPredicate("safari")
    .getPredicateBlock()
        .println("return (ua.indexOf('webkit') != -1);")
        .returns("'safari'"),

        // IE9
        new UserAgentPropertyGeneratorPredicate("ie9")
        .getPredicateBlock()
        .println("return (ua.indexOf('msie') != -1 && ($doc.documentMode >= 9));")
        .returns("'ie9'"),

        // IE8
        new UserAgentPropertyGeneratorPredicate("ie8")
        .getPredicateBlock()
        .println("return (ua.indexOf('msie') != -1 && ($doc.documentMode >= 8));")
        .returns("'ie8'"),

        // IE6
        new UserAgentPropertyGeneratorPredicate("ie6")
        .getPredicateBlock()
        .println("var result = /msie ([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)/.exec(ua);")
        .println("if (result && result.length == 3)")
        .indent()
        .println("return (makeVersion(result) >= 6000);")
        .outdent()
        .returns("'ie6'"),

        // gecko family
        new UserAgentPropertyGeneratorPredicate("gecko1_8")
        .getPredicateBlock()
        .println("return (ua.indexOf('gecko') != -1);")
        .returns("'gecko1_8'"),
    };

    static void writeUserAgentPropertyJavaScript(SourceWriter body, SortedSet<String> possibleValues) {

        // write preamble
        body.println("var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();");
        body.println("var makeVersion = function(result) {");
        body.indent();
        body.println("return (parseInt(result[1]) * 1000) + parseInt(result[2]);");
        body.outdent();
        body.println("};");

        // write only selected user agents 
        for (int i = 0; i < predicates.length; i++) {
            if (possibleValues.contains(predicates[i].getUserAgent())) {
                body.println("if ((function() { ");
                body.indent();
                body.print(predicates[i].toString());
                body.outdent();
                body.println("})()) return " + predicates[i].getReturnValue() + ";");
            }
        }

    // default return
    body.println("return 'unknown';");
}

    public String generate(TreeLogger logger, SortedSet<String> possibleValues, String fallback, SortedSet<ConfigurationProperty> configProperties) {
        for (String value : possibleValues) {
            if (!VALID_VALUES.contains(value)) {
                logger.log(TreeLogger.WARN, "Unrecognized "
                        + UserAgentGenerator.PROPERTY_USER_AGENT + " property value '"
                        + value + "', possibly due to UserAgent.gwt.xml and "
                        + UserAgentPropertyGenerator.class.getName()
                        + " being out of sync." + " Use <set-configuration-property name=\""
                        + UserAgentGenerator.PROPERTY_USER_AGENT_RUNTIME_WARNING
                        + "\" value=\"false\"/> to suppress this warning message.");
            }
        }
        assert predicates.length == VALID_VALUES.size();
        StringSourceWriter body = new StringSourceWriter();
        body.println("{");
        body.indent();
        writeUserAgentPropertyJavaScript(body, possibleValues);
        body.outdent();
        body.println("}");
        return body.toString();
    }
}
```

**MySystem.gwt.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='mysystem'>
<!-- some inherits -->
<property-provider name="user.agent" generator="com.google.gwt.user.rebind.mysystemUserAgentPropertyGenerator"/>
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.UserAgent"/>
<set-configuration-property name="user.agent.runtimeWarning" value="false"/>  
<!-- the rest of the file -->
<extend-property name="locale" values="en, it" />
</module>
```

Sadly by doing in this way I didn't solve the issue
Can anybody suggest to me any other thing to try?

Thank you

Angelo

Answer (score 2):

The way GWT modules are loaded, anything defined later **overrides** something defined earlier, and `<inherits>` are processed as if the inherited module was included in-place.

You should thus move your `<property-provider>` line **after** the `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.UserAgent"/>` line.

Comment: Hi Thomas First of all thank you for replying. Sadly I tried what you suggested but I always get the same error....I'm getting crazy...it's from 4 days I'm fighting :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clear all caches in the browser and your IDE? In intellij I often have to stop intellij idea, clear the cache/gwt dieclipse and to start intellij again to get rid of such spurious problems. Same with eclipse.

Comment: Hello Robert; thank you for answering; I don't use any IDE; I'm using maven in order to build my system and I always launch maven with clean install options; I just tried to repeat the test by deleting all caches in my IE8 but, sadly, I always get the same error...this is so frustrating